# How do I pass a capture a string in a closure without causing a compiler error?

Tags: rust, closures

The compiler issues an error on the following code, and I don't know how to fix it.  Note, it works for the non-closure (direct call) case, it's just when I try to capture the value `s` in a closure that it fails.  What's the right way to fix this?

```
fn count_letter(data : String, c : char) -> i32 {
    data.chars().filter(|x| *x == c).count() as i32
}

fn main()
{
    // Pretend this has to be a String, even though in this toy example it could be a str
    let s = "there once was a man from nantucket".to_string();

    // Works
    println!("{:?}", count_letter(s, 'n'));

    // error[E0507]: cannot move out of `s`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
    let result : Vec<(char, i32)> = ('a'..='z').map(|x| (x, count_letter(s.clone, x))).collect();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

The error is: **error[E0507]: cannot move out of `s`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure**

Comment: The `count_letter` in the first `println!` takes ownership of the string `s`. This is why you can't use it after this point. (you missed the parenthesis for `s.clone` though). If you add another `.clone` on this first use of `s`, your code is fine ;) [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=343c5a6eb4bfaf62bbe49e53aa60cb9c)

Comment: Unless you really need `count_letter` to take ownership of the string data (and thus making it required to constantly clone the string), it would be much better to pass a reference to the string: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf41dc7a668546824068090e31aa73e2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gues you want this behavior:

```
fn count_letter(data : &str, c : char) -> i32 {
    data.chars().filter(|x| *x == c).count() as i32
}

fn main()
{
    // Pretend this has to be a String, even though in this toy example it could be a str
    let s = "there once was a man from nantucket".to_string();

    // Works
    println!("{:?}", count_letter(&s, 'n'));
     
    // Also works
    let result : Vec<(char, i32)> = ('a'..='z').map(|x| (x, count_letter(&s, x))).collect();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```